# How to fix Node.js puppeteer keyboard.type() causes TypeError

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have some code that is filling out a form. It is able to find all the parts I need but it failes to type in one of them.

At first, I started by just waiting for the input fields to load, then wrote to them with `page.type()`. The username worked fine but the password failed.
I split `page.type()` to `page.click()` and then `page.keyboard.type()` in order to isolate the problem.

I'm writing with typescript and running the files with [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node)

The same error was raised on both runs:

```
TypeError: text is not iterable
    at Keyboard.type (...\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Input.js:162:24)
    at Keyboard.<anonymous> (...\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:112:23)
    at ...\src\backend\index.ts:67:37
    at step (...\src\backend\index.ts:33:23)
    at Object.next (...\src\backend\index.ts:14:53)        
    at fulfilled (...\src\backend\index.ts:5:58)
```

```
await page.waitFor('input[type="text"]')    // Makes sure the form was loaded
    await page.type('input[type="text"]', user.username);
    await page.waitFor('input[type="password"]')    // Makes sure the form was loaded
    try{
        // await page.type('input[type="password"]', user.password);
        await page.click('input[type="password"]');    // Click password field
        await page.waitFor(5000)
        await page.keyboard.type(user.password);
    }
    catch(e){
        console.error(e)
    }
    await page.waitFor('input[type="submit"]')    // Makes sure the form was loaded
    await page.click('input[type="submit"]');
```

This code definitely worked in another project I had, what can be causing this error?

Comment: Is it a string inside user.password?

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher yes

Comment: Maybe you are not passing a string, instead it's int or object. Can you double check?

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher That was it, I forgot to define the password value.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The error occurred because `user.password` was not a string. It was `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks. I have been searching the issue, and find that `undefined` is the root cause

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was passing a `Number` instead of a `String`. Number is not iterable indeed, should pass a `String`.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert number to string using **JSON.stringify**

```
await page.keyboard.type(JSON.stringify(user.password));
```